# logstash match log4j date wrapped in brackets

Tags: logstash, logstash-configuration, logstash-file

My logs start with this:

`[2017-01-12 01:02:28.975] [some other stuff] more logs. this is multiline`

I'd like to match this log and all the lines below it - ending the log entry when I see a new timestamp like the one above.

My input looks like:

```
input {
  file {
    type => "my-app"
    path => "/log/application.log"
    start_position => "beginning"
    sincedb_path => "/tmp/.sincedb"
    codec => multiline {
      pattern => "^%[{TIMESTAMP_ISO8601}]"
      what => "previous"
      negate => true
    }
  }
}
```

This doesn't appear to be matching. I know my date is in the format of `{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS}`. I just don't understand how to turn that into a logstash pattern.

Thanks

Comment: did you try using the [grok](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-filters-grok.html) filter?

Answer (score 0):

Try below Pattern in your filter
`match => {"message" => "%{DATA:date} %{TIME:timestamp} *%{GREEDYDATA:message}"}`